# Python text parsing of a PDF and search with contrast

Tags: python, pdf

I'm trying to develop a python application to analyze the text of some PDFs (for example purchase invoices) where through questions I should be able to extract information (for example total purchases, item name, etc.) based on the context of the document. The various documents analyzed have a different form. I was thinking about something with nltk. Do you have any idea how I could do it?

Thanks